# Phppgadmin page not working it displays 404 not fund error

Tags: apache2, phppgadmin

in my localhost/phppgadmin it displays like these below code what can i do to fix my issue..?
`

```
/**
 * Main access point to the app.
 *
 * $Id: index.php,v 1.13 2007/04/18 14:08:48 mr-russ Exp $
 */

// Include application functions
$_no_db_connection = true;
include_once('./libraries/lib.inc.php');
$misc->printHeader('', null, true);

$rtl = (strcasecmp($lang['applangdir'], 'rtl') == 0);

$cols = $rtl ? '*,'.$conf['left_width'] : $conf['left_width'].',*';
$mainframe = '<frame src="intro.php" name="detail" id="detail" frameborder="0" />'
```

?>
">

```
<frame src="browser.php" name="browser" id="browser" frameborder="0" />
```

```
<noframes>
<body>
    <?php echo $lang['strnoframes'] ?><br />
    <a href="intro.php"><?php echo $lang['strnoframeslink'] ?></a>
</body>
</noframes>
```

printFooter(false);
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin
>   /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phppgadmin.conf
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: it displays the following error:"cp: cannot stat '/etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin': No such file or directory
"

Comment: Replace `LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock` line with `Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default` this in `apache2.conf` file.